# Long-lasting HGETALL from replica with intensive write

Tags: redis, replication

Let's suppose that we have 2 Redis instances: master and slave. We're generating a lot of `HINCRBY` to master. All this queries are repeated on replica. Now imagine that we're starting `HGETALL` for large hash and it is taking about 10 seconds for replica to answer.

What will happen with `HINCRBY` write commands coming from master during long-lasting `HGETALL` on slave? Will slave execute all `HINCRBY` commands when `HGETALL` finished?

Comment: Yes, assuming that the master's replication buffer isn't exhausted during that 10s interval.

Comment: @ItamarHaber thank you. Is there any way of monitoring buffer size/state?

Comment: The size is configured with the ` client-output-buffer-limit` directive. However, when exhausted, the slave will perform a full resynchronization so it should be pretty evident if that is the case